# How to extract schema of a existing database in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract the schema of the database in sql server 2008.i also want to take back up from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will answer your question.

There is a tool to do this. Check out [here](http://www.antipodeansoftware.com/Home/Products). This will iterate the entire SQL server, and write all the tables, viewss, stored procedure and UDF scripts to a local drive.